# Angular material design md-autocomplete with md-max-length and pattern

Tags: angularjs, material-design, md-autocomplete

I'm using **md-autocomplete** directive as a *address for zip code* lookup. I want to limit what the user type in the control to five digit zip code only. It has to be numbers and limited to 5 numbers.

How can I achieve this in **md-autocomplete**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this with a filter: http://jsfiddle.net/uhmgp23h/2/

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="zip" />
    </div>
</body>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter)
{
    $scope.zip = '';
    $scope.$watch('zip', function(newVal, oldVal)
    {
        var value = String(newVal);   
        var number = value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g,'');
        $scope.zip = $filter('numberFixedLen')(number,5);
    });
});

app.filter('numberFixedLen', function()
{
      return function(n, len)
      {
          var num = parseInt(n);
          if (String(num).length > len) return n.substring(0, len);
          return num;
      };
});
```

This filter will restrict the field to numbers only and also limit it to 5 characters. This filter will work with any number of chars, just change the `5` to whatever you want in this line `$filter('numberFixedLen')(number,5);`

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Could you please explain how this can work with 'md-autocomplete' which is a 'Material Design' directive.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that directive